# How to use JS/React Libraries with Kotlin/JS?

Tags: javascript, kotlin-js

I’m exploring Kotlin/JS at the moment and still very new to it.

Currently I’m exploring React with Kotlin/JS. I’m wondering if there are any step by step guide on how I could use and integrate existing Libraries (or any library) thats commonly used for React Development.

What I know so far is that I can use implementation(npm(, ) to add in the library, but other than that I can’t seem to figure our how to properly access them. I’ve looked into the Kotlin/JS docs and looks like I need to write wrappers to access the imported libraries but I can’t seem to figure out how to start.
Anyone has links to tutorial I could look into? or any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I can’t seem to figure out how to start" did you try looking at [existing wrappers for JS libraries](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-wrappers)? Also, this is blatantly off-topic.

Comment: Hi @JaredSmith, those are wrappers that are readily provided for use in Kotlin/JS. I was wondering how to integrate JS Libraries that does not have the same wrappers. How was those wrappers been done so I could use the same thing to make any js library work with kotlin/js. As for this question being off-topic, I would love to edit and refine this question a bit more if you could share your thoughts on how to improve the question.

Comment: I posted that so you can read the source of the existing wrappers to see how they did it and write your own based on them. As for being off-topic, you are asking for off-site resources which violates the rules, I recommend you look at existing wrappers, try to write your own based on them, and come here with a specific question about that work when and if you get stuck. From [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow."